# Click on ul > li only works first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, click

I have an iframe and on it there is a ul list that changes the content of a div depending on what I select.

I need to get the click function for do something when the user select any of the elements in the list but it only Works the first time.

```
$("#____bl_k_dd").on("click", "li", function(){
    alert("I work")
});
```

I tried diferent functions. There is another one I tried.

```
$("#____bl_k_dd li").click(function () {
    alert("I work")
});
```

It Works only the first time, then if I click again on the ul list there is no alert.

EDIT.

Coment that the ID of the ul don't change, is always the same.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '#____bl_k_dd li', function() {`.

Comment: Did you code this inside the iframe ?

Comment: Yes, it's inside the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `#____bl_k_dd` is being removed and replaced when the content changes, you should hook your click to the body instead, something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#____bl_k_dd li", function(){
    alert("I work")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, because the given code works, you can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Petya/hx2h7gn7/1/)

```
    $("#____bl_k_dd").on("click", "li", function(){
      alert("I work");
    });
```

From jQuery documentation:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.